# background picture is cut in half

Tags: css, image, image-processing, background, background-image

I have a background image applied with the following code:

```
#paint-bg{
    background: url(../_img/contacto/paint.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 970px;
    height: 670px;
    display:block;
}
```

Nothing really extraordinary.The same as my html:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <body class="bg">
        <?php include('nav.php'); ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="paint-bg">
                    <section class="contacto">
                        <h2>Contacto</h2>
                        <p class="p1">c/ Manuel Pombo Angulo nº 18 ,planta 1ª 16</p>
                        <p class="p2">28055 Madrid</p>
                        <p class="p3">+34 629 413 049</p>
                        <p class="p4"><a href="mailto:info@rosasusaeta.com">info@rosasusaeta.com</a></p>
                    </section>
                </div>
        </div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Nothing extraordinary. But when somebody access this webpage they see the image cut in half form the left side. I've played with different parameters but as its so simple I dont know what is wrong... Please let me know how to follow...

Here you have the link of the website so you can see it for yourself, [link to web site](http://rosasusaeta.com/contacto.php).

[image]

Comment: I guess you've fixed it? as it looks fine

Comment: Looks fine to me too?

Comment: I'm on Firefox 19, and I can see the whole image fine (on the live site)

Comment: Can't reproduce this in Chrome or FF.

Comment: I see the bottom of the background is cut off. When I removed 'fixed' from the background css, it shifted and fit.

Comment: It fixed i guess as i can see entire image in firefox,IE and Chrome

Comment: You're aware that you have a bunch of javascript errors on the page we well?

Comment: What browser do you see this?? and....err just a suggestion that bg is huge...you might want to optimize it

Comment: with your comments I've chcked other browsers and it seems chrome and safaria have the problem. Maybe its something with webkit... @jason Lydon I will check these errors. This is was my first project ever... From whic element did you remove the fixed background of css? Of the painting picture or of the background image

Comment: @Riskbreaker The browser I'm using is chrome. The BG loads fine, the problem is with the paint picture. I already tried bringing down the quality of the background but it began to pixel... Regarding the paint background its a very big PNG, but I do not know what else I can do..

Comment: @Jason Lydon Just checked and I do not see any javascript erros on the page.... I dont knwo what your speaking about...

Comment: Fine in my Chrome...Are you in Mac? whats your screen resolution? tu pantalla

Comment: @Riskbreaker very strange that non your chrome you have no problem. I have a mac 10.7.5 and checking with chrome 26.0.1410.43. Mi resolucion is 1440x990. I dont know if this helps...